# iPad Safari issue for viewport

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile-safari, viewport

I have a question on iPad Safari. I have a page which onload shows in scaled up mode and as soon as I first click anywhere on screen, it immediately zooms out.

I am not showing any code, as I think this is iPad Safari behavior. I wanted to know how can i fix this issue..Is this a viewport issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: @hmthr:  You comment that it doesn't help, somebody down-votes it, and then you mark it as the correct answer.  Does it work or not?

Comment: @Sparky672 I think it is quite funny :-)